# Angular 2 - Alert user before leaving the page if page is touched

Tags: angular

We have requirement where we have to alert user if page is touched, if use select different menu application should show alert with Yes or No if user continue to proceed then only redirect should occur else it should fall back to the same page. We have tried with ngOnDestroy but, application is redirecting to next page without showing Alert.

My first approach was:

```
 ngOnDestroy()
{        
    this.touched = this.eventForm.touched;
    if (this.touched)
        this.display = true;
}
```

Now I am trying with `CanDeactivate` guard (refer to [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sRNxfXsbcWnPU818aZsu?p=preview) for an example):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router'; 
import { SidebarComponent } from './shared/sidebar/sidebar.component'; 

@Injectable() 
export class ConfirmDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<SidebarComponent> {
     canDeactivate(target: SidebarComponent) { 
          if (target.hasChanges()) { 
               return window.confirm('Do you really want to cancel?'); 
          } 
          return true; 
      } 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warn user of unsaved changes before leaving page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922071/warn-user-of-unsaved-changes-before-leaving-page)

Comment: Please check this link and its underlining repo 
https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/guard , i have implemented the can decativate guard.

Answer (score 8):

You should use `canDeactivate` guard

https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router'; 
import { SidebarComponent } from './shared/sidebar/sidebar.component'; 

@Injectable() 
export class ConfirmDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<SidebarComponent> {
     canDeactivate(target: SidebarComponent) { 
          if (target.hasChanges()) { 
               return window.confirm('Do you really want to cancel?'); 
          } 
          return true; 
      } 
}
```

refer Sample @plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/sRNxfXsbcWnPU818aZsu?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your help Maciej, I have referred 

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html 

tried to implement Deactivating Routes, in this CanDeactivateComponent  do i need to refer the menu component which I need to disable? i have followed the exact steps and registered ConfirmDeactivateGuard. Do I need to call canDeactivate explicitly? here is my ConfirmDeactivateGuard. same have been register in AppModule. Please assist.

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { SidebarComponent } from './shared/sidebar/sidebar.component';
@Injectable()
export class ConfirmDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<SidebarComponent> {

    canDeactivate(target: SidebarComponent) {
        //if (target.hasChanges()) {
            return window.confirm('Do you really want to cancel?');
        //}
       // return true;
    }
}

Comment: As far as I can see, your code should be working. Did you get any issues with it?