# Query for currently active component instances in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm trying to implement a global dirty checker in Angular.  We have a solution that requires configuring each component, but I was hoping to generalize it more.

I wired up global code that would check each active component and then signal whether or not the user should be prompted.  Or at least, I thought it was doing that.  My initial plan was listing to `router.events` for `NavigationEnd` events and inspecting the current `ActivatedRoute` because it exposes a `component` property.  However, that property is the type/class of the component and not the actual instance.

I have yet to find an API that exposes the current component instances.  Does it exist or am I stuck?

**UPDATE**

The usecase I am struggling with is not route changes, but when the window closes. When `window:beforeunload` fires, I don't have any way to ask the component instances if they are dirty.

**UPDATE 2** 
Created issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18634

Comment: Could you instead implement a generalized `canDeactivate` guard and assign that guard to each route? The canDeactivate *does* give you the instance of the component.

Comment: Yes, and I have that for route changes.  Hopefully, `canDeactivateChild` will be implemented soon and will clean that up further.  However, where I am currently struggling is when the user closes the window.  I didn't clarify that in my question, but I will update that now.

Comment: That may need to be a feature request because I don't think that there is anything to provide that for you at that point. You can post requests to: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues

Answer (score 0):

[Warn user of unsaved changes before leaving page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922071/warn-user-of-unsaved-changes-before-leaving-page)

https://medium.com/@amcdnl/angular-guards-more-than-security-c04be35adb00

Comment: These are fine examples of how to solve the problem for a particular component.  However, in our organization, I expect to have 100s if not 1000s of components and I would like to prevent everyone one of them requiring the same exact code each time.