# In typescript how to you create a decorator that adds a decorator?

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular, I'm trying to prompt the user when closing the window with a dirty form.  I have code that works with by listening to `window:beforeunload`, but the same code is duplicated on every `Component`.  I am trying to add a decorator that can be placed on the component that will mix-in the required logic, but that requires add a function and then applying a decorator on it.  My attempt is below, but it doesn't seem to be working (ie, my event listener is never called).

```
export function createOnBeforeUnload() {
    return function ($event: any) {
        console.log('calling onBeforeUnload', this, $event);
        if (this.isDirty && this.isDirty()) {
            console.log('setting message');
            $event.returnValue = DIRTY_CONFIRM_MSG;
        }
    };
}


export function DirtyChecking() {
    return function (target: any) {
        if (target.prototype) {
            console.log('adding dirty checking to', target);
            target.prototype._onBeforeUnload = createOnBeforeUnload();
            // attempt at adding the @HostListener decorator
            HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])(target.prototype._onBeforeUnload);
        }
    };
}
```

My component is

```
@DirtyChecking()
@Component({
    template: `
    <h2>Dirty Checker</h2>

    <form novalidate>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dirty">Dirty?</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="dirty" name="dirty"
               [(ngModel)]="dirty">
      </div>

    </form>
  `,
})
export class DemoDirtyCheckerComponent implements IsDirty {

    private dirty = false;

    constructor() {
    }

    toggle() {
        this.dirty = !this.dirty;
    }

    isDirty() {
        console.log('is dirty demo?', this.dirty);
        return this.dirty;
    }
}
```

The decorator is being called because I see "adding dirty checking to" in the console.  However, when I close the window `_onBeforeUnload` isn't being called like I expect to to have be.

Comment: Is there any chance you can use `CanDeactiveGuard` to do this job, so you don't need to dip in the decorator?

Comment: I'm not sure if AoT will like it. You likely have XY problem. You could probably do same thing with component inheritance or else. Is there something that prevents you from having base component class that has these decorators?

Comment: CanDeactivateGuard won't work because it isn't called when the window is closed. As for inheritance, there is probably something that could work, I just have a strong distaste for it. I was hoping for a less restrictive solution.

Comment: Is there something usefule in stewdebaker's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922071/warn-user-of-unsaved-changes-before-leaving-page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the solution suggested from @Harry Ninh

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

export abstract class IsDirtyComponent {
    abstract isDirty(): boolean;

    @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    onBeforeUnload($event: any): void {

        if (this.isDirty()) {
            $event.returnValue = 'Are you sure?';
        }
    }

}
```