# Browser Close Event in angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-directives

> How can i detect browser close event in angular 4.0.2

I have tried

1. `@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
    unloadHandler(event) {
    ...
   }`
2. `@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    ...
   }`

**But not properly working for me. Can anyone help me out. If i refresh page than also this event fires**

*Need Separate browser close event in angular2/4*

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922071/warn-user-of-unsaved-changes-before-leaving-page

Answer (score 2):

You need to set $event.returnValue if you want close event popup

```
Inside component

    @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
     public beforeunloadHandler($event) {
     $event.returnValue = "Are you sure?";
    }
```

Comment: i  wanted to clear token from local storage, i used above methods, but it removes token from local storage even if i refresh page.

Comment: window:beforeunload Yes this event is common for refresh and close, it doesn't hold anything that give us anything relevent to distinguish between refresh and close

Comment: is here any particular method for closing browser in angular2/4?

Comment: As per my research angular is not having anything to handle browser close event,you can use ngOnDestroy(): void {   //your line of code to clean up }, but I think window:beforeunload is more useful in your case.

Comment: yes that is right but, i ma clearing token on close browser but this method fires when page refresh also. So when i refresh page it logout. is there any solution according to you? either frontend or backed?

Comment: Only thing you can do , bind key event listener and set flag basis on f5 key code true/false, if it is false then do not send event.returnValue.

Comment: yes that's right, but i think it is not a best practice or valid solution.

Comment: This worked for me. But do you know why calling `window.confirm` inside beforeunloadHandler doesn't generate the popup?

Comment: Right click + Reload Page and Navigate to Browser Url -> Enter will also clear your token and you don't really want that.

Comment: the event triggered even when browser's tab is closed. Is there any lifecycle hooks which get triggered only when whole browser is closed