# How to prevent page refresh in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I want to prevent page refresh by everywhere.

I tried the code below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonServices } from '../services/common.service'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-review-prescription',
  templateUrl: './review-prescription.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../assets/css/prescriptionView.css'],
  providers:[
    CommonServices
  ]
})
export class ReviewPrescriptionComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private commonServices:CommonServices,
        private router:Router
        ){}
    ngOnInit(){
      window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
        return 'By refreshing this page you may lost all data.';
      }
  }

}
```

Tried this on `ngOnChanges()`, `ngOnInit()`, `ngOnDestroy()` even outside the component class(sorry illogical) but nothing works?

I need solution in Angular or JavaScript not in jQuery.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a bit more of your code please?

Comment: You cannot prevent page refresh. The browser user can always hit F5. The "onbeforeunload" approach will allow you to *warn* the user, but you can't prevent it.

Comment: @Pointy you are right but even warning is not working. The problem is `window.onbeforeunload` is not working :(

Comment: What do you mean "is not working"? Are there errors reported? Do you get the dialog from the browser?

Comment: @Pointy I mean when i reload the page it doesn't show warning.

Comment: Then you have not properly set up the "beforeunload" handler. The code you posted would work to show the warning dialog if it were actually called.

Comment: I posted more code that may help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922071/warn-user-of-unsaved-changes-before-leaving-page?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 13):

Try the below subscription to throw alert window on page refresh. do some user events like click over the page before trying to refresh or close the window. [check the working version here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-page-reload)

[see the official documentation on beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload)

```js
ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        var confirmationMessage = "\o/";
        console.log("cond");
        e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko, Trident, Chrome 34+
        return confirmationMessage;              // Gecko, WebKit, Chrome <34
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this really work for you? At least nothing happens in chrome when i refresh the page.

Comment: hint: do "see" the official documentation on beforeunload

Answer (score 7):

```
@HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"]) unloadHandler(event: Event) {
      event.returnValue = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution depends on why you want to prevent the page reload. If you want to prevent it because there can be unsaved changes you have actually to prevent two different behaviours:

1. Browser page reload. You can achieve this by creating an HostListener on the beforeunload event (similar to your attempt) like:

```
    @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    beforeUnloadHander() {
        // or directly false
        this.allowRedirect;
    }
```

2. Angular routing change (if you have routing): to do that you have to use a Deactivation guard on the route you want to lock, there are many ways but the most appreciated is the one that uses an interface implementation:

I. The interface sets up a couple of fields used in the angular guard to check if the we can change the router path:

```
    import { Observable } from "rxjs";
    import { HostListener } from "@angular/core";

    // see https://scotch.io/courses/routing-angular-2-applications/candeactivate
    // implementing this interface with a component in angular you can implement a candeactivate
    // guard that automatically checks if there is the canDeactivate function and
    // it allows to navigate out of the route or not
    export default interface LockableComponent {
      allowRedirect: boolean;
      canDeactivate(): boolean;
    }
```

II. Each component has to implement this interface with the method canDeactivate or the allowRedirect field (reusable in the HostListener for the problem #1) and must returning a boolean that indicates if navigation is allowed or not.

III. Create a router guard that checks this component fields for the deactivation:

```
  canDeactivate(
    component: LockableComponent,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (
      (component.allowRedirect === false ||
        (component.canDeactivate && !component.canDeactivate()))
    ) {
      // Angular bug! The stack navigation with candeactivate guard
      // messes up all the navigation stack...
      // see here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13586#issuecomment-402250031
      this.location.go(currentState.url);

      if (
        window.confirm("Sure man?")
      ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

III. Set the canDeactivate router guard in your module.routing.ts file:

```
const myRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: "locked-route-path",
        component: ComponentThatImplementsLockedInterface,
        canDeactivate: [TheCanDeactivateGuardJustMade]
      }
      //...
]
```

Comment: That's the cleanest I see. While it might be a bit overkill for some really easy app, this technique is the one that is the most modular and reusable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    alert('By refreshing this page you may lost all data.');
}
```

Please be sure to include this inside the class.

Comment: can you provide any example

Comment: code is provided in the link please refer- https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/angular-how-keep-user-from-lost-his-data-by-accidentally-leaving-the-page-before-submit-4eeb74420f0d

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a perfect solution for this but there was none of them was perfect.

I have created a solution for this and you can see the full code here.
[Prevent reload without saving](http://www.learnsharecorner.com/mukesh-salaria-795036670538905/working-angular-page-reload-shows-alert/)

Code example:
https://github.com/mukeshsalaria01/angular-show-alert-on-page-reload-without-saving-example

Answer (score 0):

> I have done it using both **RouteGuard** and pure **Javascript** code to prevent browser close tab/back/close window.

**Component:**

```
profileForm = this.fb.group({
  ClientName: ['', [Validators.required]]
});

@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) beforeUnloadHander(event: any) {
     debugger
     var isFormDirty = document.getElementById('profileformStatus').innerText;
     console.log(isFormDirty);
     if(isFormDirty == 'true'){
       return false;
     }
     else{
       return true;
     }
   }
```

**Component HTML:**

```
<div id="profileformStatus">{{profileForm.dirty ? true:false}}</div>
```

**Your Component Guard Service File(Optional):**

```
import { CanDeactivate } from "@angular/router";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { YourComponent } from "./projects/your-component";
@Injectable()

export class YourComponentCanDeactivateGuardService
    implements CanDeactivate<YourComponent> {

    canDeactivate(component: YourComponent): boolean {
        if (component.profileForm.dirty) {
            return confirm('Are you sure you want to discard your changes?');
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Your Module: add The Above Guard(Optional)**

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [YourComponentCanDeactivateGuardService]
})
```

Finally

**Update your routing module(Optional):**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'detail/:id',
        component: YourComponent,
        canDeactivate: [YourComponentCanDeactivateGuardService]
    }
];
```

Done. Now it will prevent reload/back navigation both.

Answer (score 0):

All the previous answers contains this code, but we need to add a statement to prevent the default behaviour.

> event.preventDefault()

```
@HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"])
unloadHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return event.returnValue = "Are you sure you want to exit?";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For this, you should create a Guard.

in your routing configuration file:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/homePage',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'accueil',
        component: AccueilComponent,
        canDeactivate: [GuardName]
    }]
```

By doing this you're calling your guard on the selected component

More informations [Here](https://angular.io/guide/router)

In your guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate) {
    return true/false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is really not an Angular problem; it's basic browser behavior.

Comment: Should have misunterstood his problem then

Comment: I guess you received a down vote because the guard simply doesn't work (with browser refresh).