# how to detect a page is being reloaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I need to intercept the page reload when the user clicks the reload button in the browser. I tried the following code but my break point never pops up.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router
        .events
        .subscribe((e: RouterEvent) => {
            debugger;
        });
}
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Your application restarts from scratch when the reload button is clicked. So your root component's constructor and ngOnInit method is called, for example. What concrete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I think this question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47331260/how-to-prevent-page-refresh-in-angular-4

Comment: @JBNizet I have a child component which shows up based on some conditions. At some point, if this child shows up but the user clicks the reload button, I would still wanna bring up this child.

Comment: Then make sure the condition is based on the value of the URL. If the user reloads, the app will display the route associated to that URL, and your child component will be redispayed.

Comment: @JBNizet That will need a route and an outlet. But this child needs the whole of the viewport while its parent is a 2-column layout. That is why I have to have some conditions to change the layout. Otherwise I will need a route for this child the same level as its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@HostListener("window:beforeunload")
```

Like this

```
@HostListener("window:beforeunload")
public doSomething() {
  // custom logic here
}
```

Comment: I might give this a try. Thanks!