# How to do server request on page reload?

Tags: javascript, angular

I wont to save user data on exit/reload page:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) async unloadHandler() {
    await this.api.saveUserSettings(this.userSetting);
}
```

It is sometime work, and sometime not.
in chrome network i see that the request always canceled.

Comment: If you are ok with the blocking action - you could follow the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922071/warn-user-of-unsaved-changes-before-leaving-page

Comment: @dmoo a deactivate guard isn't a blocking action. `window.alert` is a blocking action.

Comment: @Maryannah yup, was referring to the highest rated 'answer' with its use of confirm, not the ticked answer :)

Comment: @dmoo It's just that they way commented seems to say that the answer is to use a guard, and that the guard is blocking. I just stated that to not confuse the future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't stop a user from leaving the page with a non blocking action.

Instead of doing that, you should save the settings in your local storage

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) async unloadHandler() {
  localStorage.setItem('settings', this.userSetting);
}
```

And use a [resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) or an [application initializer](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) to make your request **once the page is reloaded**.